Springer Nature (sn-basic): Display of all authors in the reference list ( list with more than three authors not abbreviated with et al)
I use the sn-basic.bst bibliography of the Springer Nature template because it best fulfills the requirements of my journal.
Currently, the list of authors for publications with more than three authors is canceled after the third author and replaced by "et al".
However, I would like all authors to be displayed in the reference list.
I think this is defined in the function format.full.names. The code is shown below.
Can anyone tell me how I can change this so that all authors are shown?
Thanks in advance!
FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  numnames #2 >
                    { "," * }
                    'skip$
                  if$
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

If the journal you're hoping will publish your paper is making you use the sn-basic bibliography style, I'd say it's not a good idea to modify it right under the editorial staff's noses.

Unfortunately, the journal just provided the template, but gave no advice which of the given bibliography styles to use. Also, a complete list of authors is preferred by the journal. Nevertheless, an abbreviated one is also accepted. I still would like to use the sn-basic since it provides the required order of authors, placement of the year and so on.

@DasK - If the journal staff tells you it's accepable to use the sn-basic bibliography style, then let them know that you'll gladly go with the flow.

You actually have to modify the function format.names in sn-basic.bst. A quick workaround is to increase the maximum number of names to be printed (e.g 100 so that you are sure all authors are always printed).
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{ f{}}{jj}"
      format.name$ 't :=
     nameptr #1 >
         {
          nameptr #100 %you can change the number here
          #1 + =
          numnames #100 %you can change the number here
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              "," *
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { " " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a solution with 100 please?
